# POST data from php to my SWIFT 3

Tags: php, swift, post

Hey Hello I have a problem with my code
I have this problem for 3 days, I cannot solve it by myself.

sorry if english so bad

Here my php Code

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = @mysqli_connect('localhost', 'id2066022_oakkozht', 'oakko7596');
 mysqli_select_db($conn, "id2066022_uficondb") or die ("no database");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$numQue=$_POST["numQue"];
$dated=$_POST["dated"];
$return_arr = array();

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$insertation = "INSERT INTO uficontable (date_timestamp)
        VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
$selectation = "SELECT * FROM uficontable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

    $insertationQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $insertation);
    if (!$insertationQuery) {
        echo "Could not process your information " . mysqli_error();
    } else {
    $selectationQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $selectation);
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectationQuery))
    {
       $return_arr[] = $data;    
    }
    }
echo json_encode($return_arr);
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
```

and SWIFT

```
    func requestPost () {

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://oakkohost.000webhostapp.com/test.php") as! URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "numQue"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("post: \(responseString)")

                    }
        task.resume()
    }
   }
```

the result is

> ```
> [{"id":"147","date_timestamp":"2017-06-26 16:42:16"}]
> ```

The problem is I want use this result which the id to my label in Swift Code
How can i use this ?

Thanks for answer

Comment: you should to convert it into swift dictionary by using jsonserialization

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Can u help me please ?